# LT: Is there any benefit to iOS 8 family sharing for couples without kids?

Tags: icloud, ios, family-sharing

Is there any benefit to iOS 8 Family Sharing for couples besides finding each other's lost devices and sharing purchases if you don’t have kids? For example there are features like calendar sharing that are possible to do through iCloud without family sharing.

Answer (score 1):

yes, most likely.  it has single credit card app store purchases, and can...
"share purchases from iTunes, iBooks, and the App Store without sharing accounts"
pretty useful, i think

Comment: Yes, 'buy one, get one free' is good, plus not having to know your spouse's password to track their phone if they lose it, or you're trying to figure out which clothes shop they went in while you were looking at car spares ;-)